# Convert ASCII code to UTF-8 with single quotes in PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding

I've a problem with encoding. The output I want is:

```
string(17) "New &amp; old"
```

This is also the output when I'm using double quotes.

This is my code. I can't change the single quotes because it's the output of another function.

```
$string = 'New \x26amp\x3Bamp\x3B old';
$string = iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $string);
var_dump($string);
```

This is my output:

```
string(26) "New \x26amp\x3Bamp\x3B old"
```

So how can I change this behavior when using single quotes. Can you convert a string from single quotes to double quotes?

Comment: You input format is not `UTF-8` that is why your script would not work .... its better you just `preg_replace` or `str_replace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\x([0-9A-F]{2})/', function ($m) {
    return pack('H*', $m[1]);
}, $str);
```

It's replacing hex notation with the actual byte it represents. It doesn't have much to do with Unicode.

Comment: damn dude you saved my life with this approach, thanks